# Html scraping with JS support

Tags: screen-scraping, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape a company web page for automation purposes but the embedded scripts in the page prevent me to fully replicate the request. The biggest pain is in the script generated cookies.

I thought of automating IE with Watin but I am not comfortable with this solution under a service application.

What are your advices in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options.

The easiest is to generate the cookies in your script. You will have to read the javascript code yourself and figure out what it is doing and duplicate. Fiddler is always your friend when scraping.

[Htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is a java web browser library with  JavaScript support. It has no gui and is made for testing web applications.

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) will driver a browser much the same way watir does, but it has rich api support for most major languages.

Answer (score 1):

[screen-scraper](http://screen-scraper.com/) is another tool (java based) that aims at being easy to use.

The basic idea is as Byron said- you will have to figure out what cookies are getting set (web proxy tools like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com), or browser extensions like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and Chrome's dev tools will come in handy).

So, you don't necessarily have to read or even execute the javascript on the page to imitate the same requests. Just use a proxy tool to see what cookies your browser is sending to the server, and once you know what cookies the site expects to receive, set them manually in whatever script or tool you use to do your scraping and you'll be golden.